# Config Automapper to ignore type when it's an inner-inner property but not inner property

Tags: c#, automapper

This one takes a little explaining. I have a set of types such that;

```
public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
}

public class MayHaveChild
{
    public Child Value { get; set; }
    public int MayID { get; set; }
}

public class MustNotHaveChild { get; set; }
{
    public List<MayHaveChild> MayValues { get; set; }
}
```

In the above scenario, I want any mapping of `MayHaveChild` to have the values for the `Child` object, *except* when I have mapped `MustNotHaveChild`. E.g.;

When I have

```
//...some code
MayHave obj = Mapper.Map<MayHaveChild>(childObj);
// I want to be able to access obj.Child.ID
```

But when I have

```
//...some code
MustNotHave obj = Mapper.Map<MustNotHaveChild>(notHaveObj);
// I want to be able to access obj.MayValues[0].MayID but 
// *not* obj.MayValues[0].Value
```

I've been through the automapper documention on nesting, polymorphism, lists, etc and I can't find anything that quite matches what I want.

I could solve this by having a inheriting the MayHave class to a MustNotHave variant but this would involve changing quite a lot of existing code. Is there a way to configure Automapper in the manner I need?

Comment: What do the source types look like? That is, what are you mapping *to* these classes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code above *are* the source types

Comment: What are the types of `childObj` and `notHaveObj`?

Comment: Assume that they have the same properties. In practice, I'm mapping entity objects to DTOs for transfer and back again. There's no significant difference and isn't relevant to this issue

Comment: Okay-- just checking for purposes of coming up with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to configure AutoMapper the way I wanted without going down the inheritance route - though this proved less problematic than I thought. I did something like the following;

```
public class NoChild : MayHaveChild
{
}

public class MustNotHaveChild { get; set; }
{
         //       \/--datatype change here
    public List<NoChild> MayValues { get; set; }
}
```

Then, later in the AutoMapper config;

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MayHave, NoChild>()
      .ForMember(c => c.Child, opt => opt.Ignore());
```